# Excel Formula to compare two columns for values, if none populate with data from 3rd column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns R,T,U,V. If column T and Column U have no value, I would like it to populate with the value from Column R. If either Column T or Column U have a value, the value in Column V should be 0.
All three columns are formulas from other areas of the spreadsheet. It looks like this:
[EXAMPLE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUJHz.png)

Comment: `=IF(AND(T2="",U2=""),R2,0)`

Comment: This results in all 0- if there are no values in the two columns T & U , I need the V column to populate with the R column.

Comment: Please post examples of the formula in T and U.

Comment: Yes the example you show has blanks, but you also say column T and U has formulas so are the formulas in column T and U returning blank or something else? That matters to the formula construction in column V.

Comment: Yes, the formulas are returning blanks.

Comment: Please post examples.  there is a difference between `" "` and `""`

Comment: I fixed my formula in Column T based on your note of the quote marks, and now it gives me the results I was looking for. Thank you!!